# How to decompose into BCNF while preserving all functional dependencies

Tags: database-theory, databases

I have a relation R = {A,B,C} and F={AB -> C , C -> B}.
In order to check if R is in BCNF.

I checked if AB and C are both superkeys and since C is not a superkey I conclude R is not in BCNF.

After decomposing R into BCNF, I have two relations :

```
R1(C,B)   F1{ C -> B}
R2(A,C)   F2{ A -> C}
```

Now since A and C are both superkeys, I can conclude that now R(R1, R2) is in BCNF.

But after computing (F1 U F2)+, I can't derive AB -> C and so I lose that FD.

My question is, how can I decompose than into BCNF while preserving FD's?

Comment: Your `R(R1, R2)` is not information equivalent to the original `R` -- that is, there are facts you can represent in `R` that you can't represent with `(R1, R2)`. Then it's not a 'lossless join' decomposition. So you haven't "decomposed"; you've just created a fresh schema with the same attribute names. Why do you think bare `C` has to be a superkey? (It's not.) Form the closure of the FDs then look again.

Comment: According to what i know, for a relation R to be in BCNF, R should be in 3NF and every FD X-> Y in R, X should be a super key. That is why I am checking if AB is superkey and C is superkey. I dont understand how to decompose this any further while preserving the FD AB -> C

Comment: Your "I have these FDs" doesn't make sense. "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must given. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097) PS Decomposition to BCNF preserving FDs is not always possible.

Answer (score 0):

this very example is discussed [in the first place I looked](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form#Achievability_of_BCNF).

The short answer is that you cannot always achieve all of

- BCNF;
- an information-equivalent schema;
- using keys as the only declared constraint(s).

Pick any two.

In this case you must retain `R = {A, B, C}`, with key `{A, B}` -- then we can't losslessly decompose `R`. In order to represent the FD `C -> B` as a relation with a suitable key, you need `R1 = {C, B}` with key `{C}`. So far we've achieved BCNF. To retain information equivalence, you need an Inclusion Dependency (aka Foreign Key constraint) `R[C] ⊆ R1[C]`.

Strictly speaking to retain info equivalence, that Inclusion Dependency should probably be an Equality Dependency. But this is a contrived example, so nobody in practice would do that.

Comment: So what foreign key can we add in R1 because we cant add attribute A in R1. In order to preserve FDs we will end up with AB -> C

Comment: Can we decompose R into

R1(C,B)     F1={C -> B}
R2(A,B,C)   F2={AB->C}

Here C and AB are superkey we can say R(R1,R2) is in BCNF

ALso (F1 U F2)+ = F+.

Comment: At least look at wikipedia before you ask any more questions. It has an article on foreign keys; see also Inclusion Dependencies under 'Referential Integrity'.  Stackoverflow has over 100 q's tagged [bcnf]. Or what does your textbook say? Foreign keys are not "in" a relation, they're _between_ relations. I gave the constraint needed.